# correlation of encrypted images adjacent pixels

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, correlation, pixel

I have the following mentioned formula to find the correlation of adjacent pixels.

```
a=image;
a1=a(:,1:end-1);
a2=a(:,2:end);
cor=corrcoef(double(a1(:)),double(a2(:)));
```

How to find the horizontal, vertical and diagonal correlation of adjacent pixels?

If this formula is correct then how I should make changes here for all the three types?

Comment: Do you understand that code?

Comment: @AnderBiguri i understand just that a1 is all rows and n-1 col while a2 is same matrix but col will be from 2nd till end.to find the correlation of each next pixel, i think this is horizontal correlation , for columns might be the rows and col will be shifted, but what about for diagonal?if i am wrong so please guide me.thanks